# Oracle SQL developer is throwing an error message

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE TABLE eNB_INFO (
  eNBID INTEGER,
  eNB_name VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  eNB_address VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  eNB_structure VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  eNB_RBS INTEGER,
  eNB_cabinet BOOLEAN,
  eNB_PLMNID INTEGER,
  eNB_MCC INTEGER,
  eNB_MNC INTEGER,
  eNB_mncLength INTEGER,
  eNB_DUL_count INTEGER,
  eNB_tac INTEGER,
  eNB_primary_DUL_name VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  eNB_inter_DU VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  eNB_DU_one_type INTEGER,
  eNB_XMU_one VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  eNB_XMU_one_port_one VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  eNB_XMU_one_port_two VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  eNB_DU_type_two VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  eNB_XMU_two VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  eNB_XMU_two_port_one VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  eNB_XMU_two_port_two VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
)
```

> Error report -
> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

Answer (score 0):

There's no Boolean datatype in Oracle SQL. Therefore, substitute it by *something else*. For example, a number (0/1) or char (N/Y) or whatever you find appropriate. For example:

```
eNB_cabinet NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, --BOOLEAN,
```

When you remove the last (superfluous) comma, then:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE eNB_INFO (
  2    eNBID INTEGER,
  3    eNB_name VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  4    eNB_address VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  5    eNB_structure VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  6    eNB_RBS INTEGER,
  7    eNB_cabinet NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, --BOOLEAN,
  8    eNB_PLMNID INTEGER,
  9    eNB_MCC INTEGER,
 10    eNB_MNC INTEGER,
 11    eNB_mncLength INTEGER,
 12    eNB_DUL_count INTEGER,
 13    eNB_tac INTEGER,
 14    eNB_primary_DUL_name VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
 15    eNB_inter_DU VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
 16    eNB_DU_one_type INTEGER,
 17    eNB_XMU_one VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
 18    eNB_XMU_one_port_one VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
 19    eNB_XMU_one_port_two VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
 20    eNB_DU_type_two VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
 21    eNB_XMU_two VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
 22    eNB_XMU_two_port_one VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
 23    eNB_XMU_two_port_two VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)
 24  );

Table created.

SQL>
```